# Обновление без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Задача в следующем, есть скрипт:

```
if($Num == 2){
echo 'ОК';
}else{
    echo 'Если значение $Num не ровняется 2, то необходимо обновить страницу и заного выполнить скрипт.';
}
```

Дак вот, скрипт должен выполняться сначала вновь и вновь до тех пор, пока не сработает условие `if($Num == 2)`, значение это я получаю из запроса к базе. Сейчас в случае когда срабатывает `else` в нём просто идёт мгновенный редирект на эту жи страницу, и тем самым страничка оновляется до тех пор, пока из  базы не достанется число 2. Всё это прекрасно раотает.

Но хотелось бы сделать так, чтоб обновление скрипта происходило без перезагрузки странички, и желательно что-бы во время поиска значения и обновлений просто на странице находилась картинка с анимацией полосы загрузки. И когда число 2 находится, только тогда уже выводилось условие.

Как такое реализовать? В какую сторону копать? Спасибо.

Comment: копайте в сторону AJAX

Comment: Смотрите сколько раз задавали подобный вопрос другие участники: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B  Ведь можно воспользоваться поиском, не правда ли?

Answer (score 2):

```
        if ($num!=2){
     ?>
        <script>
        function check(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'file.php', //В этом файле делаете запрос в БД и возвращаете результат
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.num!=2){
                        check();
                    }else{
                        alert('OK');
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
        <?php 
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Вот как это сделал я
обновление блока каждую секунду

```js
<script>setInterval(function(){
$("#stor").load("# #stor"); }, 1000); // 1000 это 1 секунда
</script>
```

```html
<div id"stor">
Здесь ваше содержимое блока!
</div>
```